# Pandas read_sql_query still running in the background even though connection is closed?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I have a closed connection:

```py
Config = dict(server = serverSample,
              port = 1433,
              username = username_input,
              password = password_input)
conn_str = (‘Server ={server},  {port}; + ‘TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes’)
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r’Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};’ + conn_str.format(**config)
)
Do = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
conn.close()
```

Right after I use the `read_sql_query` method I put the data into `DataFrame`.

For some reason, I got notified by the data guy that my connection was still going on for a while.

Does the `close` method actually stop the SQL from running, or I have to do sth else to stop the query from running in the server?

I’m using `pyodbc`.

Comment: Could you share more code with the details of  `conn` object creation and the place where you call `read)_sql_query` and close the connection.

Comment: I’ve edited my question with a more detailed code. Could you please let me know if it works?

Comment: Are you running this Python code on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I’m using anaconda on window machine

Comment: @DatNguyen - Okay, and when "data guy" said that your connection was still "going on for a while" did he say approximately how long? On Windows machines the default configuration of Microsoft's ODBC Drivers for SQL Server enables connection pooling, but the default timeout is just 60 seconds so I wouldn't expect to see a "closed" connection hang around for longer than that. (You can check the "Connection Pooling" tab of the ODBC Administrator to see what the "Pool Timeout" actually is on your machine.)

Comment: He said it was approximately 4 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you pass as the `conn` object to the `read_sql_query` method call.

1. If you pass `Connection` object it should be enough, but the problem could be with the place where you close the connection. Maybe this code is unreachable.
2. If you pass the `Engine` object. You should dispose of the connection:

```py
conn.dispose()
```

3. You could also try turning off the pooling. [Details are in the thread](http://groups.google.com/group/pyodbc/browse_thread/thread/320eab14f6f8830f/9d352676ea3ff7b6):

```py
import pyodbc


pyodbc.pooling = False
```

4. One more option is to use the connection as a `context_manager` and `commit` and not close the connection. [This approach is preferred by `pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/43):

```py
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(config) 
with conn:
    crs = conn.cursor()
    do_stuff
    # conn.commit() will automatically be called when Python leaves the outer `with` statement
    # Neither crs.close() nor conn.close() will be called upon leaving the the `with` statement!!
```

Comment: I’ve put in more detail for the code. Could you please check and see if my close connection is at the right place? Thanks